# Automate a sql query for specific dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting, date

I am writing a 'select, from, where' query in SQL and I want the query to be valid only between specific monthly dates the last day of each month to the second last day of the next month. Is there a way to automate that query so that I do not have to change the dates every month?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have a date field on whatever table/tables you are querying
you can just add this `where` clause to any of your queries to keep the results between "the last day of the current month" and  "the second to last day of the next month"

```
    WHERE 
    dateField >= CAST(DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) as date)
    AND dateField <= CAST(DATEADD(d, -2, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0)) as date)
```

Comment: Please never use [an inclusive upper bound for date/time types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i am not using between or time. just the date with specific operators

Comment: i am using open-ended date ranges

Comment: 1) We don't know the actual type of the field, which may not be `Date`.  2) It's less about `BETWEEN` itself, and more about the inclusive upper-bound. 3) It makes the calculation _stridable_ - that is, the next start condition as the previous end condition.